# How to remove axis line from Rechart React graph?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

How to remove line from x-axis to only have the values left for the UI?

```jsx
<AreaChart
    data={data}
    margin={{
        top: 10,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    }}
  >
    <Tooltip />
    <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#814587" strokeWidth={3} />
</AreaChart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by setting the `tickLine` and `axisLine` attributes of `XAxis` to false:

```jsx
<XAxis dataKey="name" tickLine={false} axisLine={false} />
```